# How to detect a change in a variable when everytime its value is changed in angular

Tags: angular

I would like to detect the change in variable which is of type int everytime the value is changed based on that i have do few operations to be performed .

The variable is int value which changes on button click.

I have tried it using @Input which is totally doesn't suit my requirement.

```
addWhereCondition() {
    ++this.numberOfWhereConditions;
  }
  deleteWhereCondition() {
    if (this.numberOfWhereConditions > 1) {
      --this.numberOfWhereConditions;
    } else {
      this.numberOfWhereConditions = 1;
    }
  }
```

numberOfWhereConditions is the variable which is changed and need to detect that change

Comment: Can you show us the code that will change `numberOfWhereConditions`, or the logic that make `numberOfWhereConditions`  change in general.

Comment: It is simple int value which is changed based on clicking " +"  and "-" buttons in UI

Comment: So you want to call `addWhereCondition()` when the button is clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a getter and setter for it. Before the constructor...

```
private _numberOfWhereConditions: number;

get numberOfWhereConditions(): number {
    return this._numberOfWhereConditions
}

set numberOfWhereConditions(newNum: number) {
    if (this._numberOfWhereConditions !== newNum) { // if the new number is not the same as the old number 
    // Logic for what happens when there is a change detected
    this._numberOfWhereConditions = newNum; // You do need to explicitly set the new number
}
```

Within the HTML, you would call `numberOfWhereConditions` and within the typescript, you would call `this.numberOfWhereConditions`.

Here's a [tutorial article](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/typescript-setters-getter).